# If cell is empty, find and capture neighboring cell values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

```
      A           B        C
0     Success     1.5     AAA
1     Duplicate           BBB
2     NaN         1.5     CCC
3     Rejected            DDD
3     Rejected            EEE
```

I am looking to capture each value in the C column when B is empty. The goal is to store this in a list.

The list would contain BBB,DDD,EEE

I've been searching on Stack for a bit and can quite find this answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the given description, you can try this to get the list of values of column C when column B values are empty. Read more about tolist [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html)

```
required_list = df.loc[df['B'].isna(), 'C'].tolist()
```

Now you can iter the required list as per your requirements.

Comment: I think this does the trick but how do I gain access to the list so I can iterate through the values again? I had a list set globally and was trying to append but if there is an easier way just to grad the values, I rather go that route. Thank you by the way this has been real helpful. @mahendra

Comment: You just need to assign the list to a variable. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df[df["B"].isnull()]["C"].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do you

```
import numpy as np

df[D] = np.where(df[B].isnull(),df[C],None)
list = df[D].dropna()
```